# Best way to server custom CSS

Tags: magento-1.9

Just wondering the best practice for serving custom CSS files? File dir location for files as well as best way to link said files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add display:inline-block; to the blocks that should display as inline, not the divs above it. The following css makes them align horizontal.

```
.widget.widget-static-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I also see your stylesheet: style1.css doesn't get loaded. you should check that out. As an advice on your problem. If you might think you should brush up your css and html skills a bit, i suggest you take the free css and html course at the link below. It's fun trust me.

https://www.codecademy.com/